# Dynamic pivot and initialization with a constant (without sum)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two Tables: TbOrder and TbProduct. These tables are correlated by a condition on a number progression through the '&' operator. If the condition is true I should assign the product to the relative order.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TbOrder](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Flag] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TbOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TbProduct](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Flag] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TbProduct] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[TbOrder] ([Id], [Flag]) VALUES (1, 5124)
INSERT [dbo].[TbOrder] ([Id], [Flag]) VALUES (2, 10507925)
INSERT [dbo].[TbOrder] ([Id], [Flag]) VALUES (3, 10053569)
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (1, 4, N'Prod1')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (2, 1024, N'Prod2')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (3, 4096, N'Prod3')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Prod4')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (5, 1, N'Prod5')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (6, 8, N'Prod6')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (7, 512, N'Prod7')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (8, 32, N'Prod8')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (9, 16, N'Prod9')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (10, 128, N'Prod10')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (11, 64, N'Prod11')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (12, 1, N'Prod12')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (13, 8192, N'Prod13')
INSERT [dbo].[TbProduct] ([Id], [Flag], [Name]) VALUES (14, 16384, N'Prod14')
```

The query and the result are as follow:

```
select o.Id OrderId, o.Flag OrderFlag, p.Id ProductId,
p.Flag ProductFlag, p.Name ProductName from TbOrder o
inner join TbProduct p on (o.Flag & p.Flag)=p.Flag
```

[image]

I tried with Pivot but the result compared to the first query remained unchanged (removing the line --'x').

```
select * from
    (select o.Id OrderId, o.Flag OrderFlag, p.Id ProductId, p.Flag ProductFlag, p.Name ProductName from TbOrder o
    inner join TbProduct p on (o.Flag & p.Flag)=p.Flag) t

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

        select @cols += QUOTENAME(Name) + ','
        FROM TbProduct 
        ORDER BY FLAG;
        SET @cols = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1);
        print @cols;

        SELECT @query = '
            SELECT t.* FROM t
        PIVOT 
        (
        --'x'
        FOR t.Name IN( ' + @cols + ' )
        ) AS pivot_table; ';
        execute(@query)
```

What I would like obtain instead is a single row for each order and only the product name for which the condition is true (marked with an 'x' in the order row) are columns.

[image]

I thank in advance anyone who tries to solve this.

Comment: Can you add the create table with the inserts?

Comment: Just did it, thanks.

Comment: No...posting pictures of data is not useful. Juan was asking for the create table statements to go along with the inserts that you posted.

Comment: ok, hope it's good so.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand what you want as output.

Comment: The last picture is what I'd like to get as output.

Comment: Can't you just pivot and then just do CASE when not null -> 'x' for each of the pivoted columns after the pivot?

Comment: always in sql you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `transform` query, you found out `allProducts` and `allOrders`. Then you can generate all combinations using `CROSS JOIN`.

Now you try to match each combination with the data already on `transfrom`, for every match you assign X.

Now with that data you can do a `DINAMIC PIVOT`. I skip because looks like you know how to do it.

[**SQL DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21d4dfd7e9a1909fb15b5e1a51771aee&hide=7)

```
WITH transform as (
   select o.Id OrderId, o.Flag OrderFlag, p.Id ProductId,
          p.Flag ProductFlag, p.Name ProductName 
   from TbOrder o
   inner join TbProduct p 
      on (o.Flag & p.Flag) = p.Flag
), allProducts as (
   SELECT distinct ProductName
   FROM transform
), allOrders as (
   SELECT distinct OrderFlag
   FROM transform
)
SELECT O.OrderFlag, 
       P.ProductName, 
       CASE WHEN T.ProductName IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 'X' 
       END as flag
INTO   partial_result     
FROM allProducts P
CROSS JOIN allOrders O
LEFT JOIN transform T
  ON O.OrderFlag = T.OrderFlag
 AND P.ProductName= T.ProductName;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.ProductName) 
            FROM partial_result c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT OrderFlag, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select OrderFlag
                    , ProductName
                    , flag
                from partial_result
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for ProductName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

execute(@query);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the support but I would need a last help as I can't pivot.

Comment: To prevent the error from the second execution"There is already an object named 'partial_result' in the database." I added this line at the begin. ```IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.partial_result', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.partial_result;```